# Make ProblemDetails return XML instead of json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using the middleware from khellang in .NET6 about the problemdetails.
The problem is that even if I specify a Produces("text/xml"),  I get always a json ProblemDetails (in json format). I tried to change the order of the formatters but no luck.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [Consumes("text/xml")]
    [Produces("text/xml")]
    public IActionResult Hook([FromBody] string content)
    {
        throw new Exception("error");
    }


        builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(options =>
        {
            //options.ContentTypes.Clear();
            //options.ContentTypes.Add(new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            options.IncludeExceptionDetails = (ctx, ex) =>
            {
                ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
                return env.IsEnvironment("Local") || env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsStaging();
            };
            options.MapToStatusCode<NotImplementedException>(StatusCodes.Status501NotImplemented);
            options.MapToStatusCode<HttpRequestException>(StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable);
            options.MapToStatusCode<Exception>(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        });

        ..........

        builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        });
```

[image]

I was able to trigger the issue by running the microsoft factory

```
 }).ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                var probleDetailsFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                    .GetRequiredService<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ProblemDetailsFactory>();
                var problemDetails = probleDetailsFactory.CreateValidationProblemDetails(context.HttpContext, context.ModelState);

                problemDetails.Detail = "Detail";
                problemDetails.Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

               return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails)
                {
                    ContentTypes = { Application.Xml }
                };


....
```

Looks like Hellang is relying on the Microsoft ProblemDetailsFactory which for somereasons always returns a JSON serialized object.
So the problem should be somehow in the Microsoft Factory

Comment: Try `"application/xml"`

Comment: I tried it already. same problem

Comment: `builder.Services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();`

Comment: I tried this as well without success. I'm almost thinking to leave hellang implementation.

Comment: Wait a sec, just realized it's the exception page. That has separate handling, you are using `AddProblemDetails` with various functions I don't recognize. Are you perhaps using ProblemDetailsMiddleware? What happens if you move `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` before that line?

Comment: AddProblemDetails is the Hellang plugin

Comment: I found out so far that its a problem of microsoft. Looks like if I run : var probleDetailsFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                        .GetRequiredService<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ProblemDetailsFactory>();
                    var problemDetails = probleDetailsFactory.CreateValidationProblemDetails(context.HttpContext, context.ModelState);
It will always return always only json even with XML headers

Comment: Like I said, did you try moving the `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` up to the top?

Comment: Yes i did..no effect

Comment: What about `return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails) { Formatters = {new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter()} }`

Comment: Well this looks to work. but ideally i would like to apply this globally, i mean also in the case when hellang is catching Exceptions, otherwise where is the point to use the hellang plugin. Also I'm in a situation that I would like to accept both XML and JSON

Comment: Looking at the docs and sample code, seems you need to call `app.UseProblemDetails();` and if using MVC you also need to call `services.AddProblemDetailsConventions()`

Comment: indeed it relies on MS Problem details, it references Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails :)

Comment: I was thinking to override somehow the Microsoft or Hellang factory but no idea from where to start

Comment: ok lets try to narrow down, is it a net core minimal or MVC Api ? to double check all running Net 6 correct ? ALSO: to avoid being sticked to a 3rd party library, what you only need is return exceptions in XML and nothing else ?

Comment: Exception and Validation. I tried both with MVCAPI and with just controllers with builder.Services.AddControllers. Everything works as expected only all the exceptions and validation errors are returned as json. the actual return Data is returned as XML as expected.

Comment: I use newtonsoft as an external package not as an MVC integration Mvc.Newtonsoft.json. maybe this can be the issue ?

Comment: Is there any update to the issue?